# Can't get data from select element vue.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

[image]I have tried different methods to make the selection of data from a `select` item work but still having issues, that is, I can't bind it to a model. The only way I have made this to work before is to make use of `v-if` but the `select` element lose its `css styling`. The `select` element is populated dynamically and I have tried different method and I am stuck with this at the moment.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      title: "",
      examType: "",
      classes: "",
      subjects: "",
      subjs:[],
      ndata:"",
      typeOptions: [
                @foreach($types as $t) 
                    { text: '{{@$t->title}}', value: '{{@$t->id}}' },
                @endforeach
            ]
    }
  });
```

**Select Element**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Exam Type: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <select name="examType" data-placeholder="Exam Type" class="select required" v-model="examType" >
      <option></option>
      <option v-for="p in typeOptions" v-bind:value="p.value">@{{ p.text }}</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

At the moment, no error is reported to the console. How can I get selected data from the select element?

Comment: `classes` property is an array or a string?

Comment: The property bound to the `<select>`'s `v-model` (i.e., `examType`) contains the value of the selected option ([demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rZXNLY)). Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: @tony19 yes, there is no value when I select an option

Comment: How/when are you determining the value?

Comment: Please update the question to show the code used to listen to the option selection, and console log. The exact event monitored and the data being logged are relevant details.

Comment: I just added a screenshot. Look at the vue console and you will found that the value is not shown when selected.

Comment: i had tried you code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/56m1hrok/) and it works when i select an item it will be shown

Comment: Yea, but mine is not behaving the way it should

Comment: pls explain `The only way I have made this to work before is to make use of v-if`. This may give us some insight.

Comment: @JacobGoh using `v-if` to create the exam type select element after at least a letter is entered in the textbox.

Comment: I guess.. you are using jquery or other JS code outside of Vue to transform the `select` element, and it destroys Vue's property on the `select` element. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobGoh A good one, I just removed the `class="select required"` from the element and it worked, but this will remove my styling.

Comment: you may see https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/ for workaround. or use Vue compatible library like https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select